# Change Firefox title bar programatically (like IE with registry setting)

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, firefox

I need to change the firefox window title like I would do for internet explorer ([like this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176497)). Is it possible or do I need to somehow install an extension and hack this setting into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going the route proposed by plod I noticed that extension's code checks for the firefox branding, so i found [this page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Rebranding_Firefox) on how customize it. With a little python+ziplib I was able to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

is there something wrong with installing an addon like: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/14576 I guess that the code for this addon will give you an idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in changing the static standard Window title (Not the way the page title, etc is arranged), don't want to install an extension just to do this, and to update the chosen answer info to Firefox 10 (and probably a few versions +- this) procedures :

1. In Firefox, alter URI below with specifics about location of your FF install ("A" below is for a standard non-portable version, installed in c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox... "B" is the relative location of the file for the portable version - Remember to amend the drive / base directory('s)) and open it in a text/html/xml editor.

   A] jar:file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/chrome/omni.ja!/chrome/en-US/locale/branding/brand.dtd
   B] jar:file:///../FirefoxPortable/App/Firefox/omni.ja!/chrome/en-US/locale/branding/brand.dtd
2. Edit any of the values to "customize" FF Window title, "brand shortname", "vendor shortname", or trademark text (The last will probably be a clear violation of the licence, though) and save file to a temporary location (like the desktop)
3. Exit firefox
4. Browse to directory (as above) that contains your omni.ja file
5. [Just in case] Make a copy of omni.ja
6. Open omni.ja with a program that can open/create .zip files
7. In zip directory chrome/en-US/locale/branding, delete existing brand.dtd
8. Add new brand.dtd from your temporary file location, in it's place, and (if necessary) save new zip file to overwrite original
9. Start Firefox again

Comment: 1.) not clear if OP asks about the part of title being set by <title> or the one related to product name; 2.) neither the link brought by OP or the answer are programatic, right? If so, it deserves a title edit